# Catching FreePascal Exception in GDB

Tags: exception, gdb, pascal, freepascal

I have a huge pascal code compiled with fpc.
I am getting random "EInOutError" exception and I am trying to debug it using gdb.

I already tried break fpc_raiseexception, catch throw, catch exception, catch catch. Nothign seems to work...

How can I break (to have a backtrace at gdb) when a exception is raisen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A breakpoint on fpc_raiseexception should be a good thing.

Don't use gdb "catch" functionality relating to exceptions. Those are for GCC C++ exceptions, not for FPC.